# Ways to Show Relative Rank?

Tags: info-visualisation, data, numbers, comparison, information-design

I am comparing 3 columns of data with multiple rows. For each row I want to show the highest, lowest and middle number. The middle number is not the mean.

I've considered "1st, 2nd, 3rd" but I don't want to convey a higher/lower number is the best choice. Sometimes having the highest number would actually be bad but other times it would be good. I'm looking for a way to point that out more easily as well.

I've also considered using up and down arrows but I'm not sure what I'd use to represent the middle number.

Comment: Order the rows in each column to always be 1st, 2nd & 3rd. If you can't do this you could create a legend based on font-weight, font-color or some other visual differentiator. If none of the above suggestions work, post an example, they always help :)

Comment: could you provide an image or mockup?

Comment: @rewobs as a very quick mockup this would be what I'm currently trying! [imgur](http://i.imgur.com/KzPLdCg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only have 3 possible values in each row, there is no need to identify the middle one.  Mark the high and low values with a simple symbol, such as red 'H' or a blue 'L', a plus and minus, or even full text, if you have the space.  Make sure that the users can clearly differentiate between the values and your markings, maybe encapsulate them in some kind of circle or parentheses.  Good luck!

Comment: Your welcome!  Good luck!